# Why can't Chromium connect to http://[::1]:8080/ (i.e. IPv6 localhost)?

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, ipv6

For developing a statically generated website on my laptop running Debian, I use [weborf](http://galileo.dmi.unict.it/wiki/weborf/) running on IPv6 localhost, port 8080: `weborf -i ::1 -p 8080 -b .`.

I can connect to `http://[::1]:8080/` without issues with [Conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) as well as Iceweasel (Debian's unbranded Firefox, release 35.0).

But with [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home) (the free base of the non-free Google Chrome browser) version 39 as currently shipped with Debian Unstable, I only get the following error message:

> This webpage is not available
>
> The server at [::1] can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Chromium from accessing the network.
>
> Error code: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Why does Chromium try to resolve anything in that URL if it only contains an IP address and no host names at all?

Interesting also StackExchange claims that "Links cannot contain '[::1]'" which is clearly wrong. But it even doesn't allow me to leave that URL in there unquoted. :-(

Comment: I'd suggest you address to the chromium people.

Comment: Works for me on Fedora and I didn't have to do anything. It's probably something peculiar to the way the Debian package maintainers built it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having same issue with Chrome 39 on OS X.
It seems like launching Chrome with `--enable-ipv6` helps.

Comment: Thanks, that helped indeed. But why the heck does Chrome/Chromium not enable IPv6 by default, not even if the machine itself has IPv6 connectivity and Google is one of the big IPv6 promoters. I don't get it.

Comment: I got no idea really. I'm not sure why it's not configurable via about:config either. Passing cli flags to .app in osx is a pain. Funny part that Safari works.