# DNS issue accessing localhost IP address in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dns, localhost

In Internet Explorer and Firefox I can access the web server on my computer by either `localhost` or its IP address `[::1]` but in Chrome the IP address isn't working and gives me this error:

> The server at `[::1]` can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

Why is Chrome attempting a DNS lookup for an IP address?

This issue exists on both Windows and Linux and at home and at work so I don't think it has anything to do with misconfigured settings. I also tried HTTPS and different ports and the same thing happens.

I should also note that once upon a time it was working, I noticed it quite a while ago but never thought much of it until now.

Comment: What happens when you try `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @TD.512 That also works in all browsers, but I would prefer not using IPv4 if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224215
it looks like a bug in chromium/chrome. It also might be worth a look at: [Why can't Chromium connect to http://[::1]:8080/ (i.e. IPv6 localhost)?](https://superuser.com/questions/852484/why-cant-chromium-connect-to-http-18080-i-e-ipv6-localhost)

The fix as it seems would be to launch chrome with: `--enable-ipv6`

> I'm having same issue with Chrome 39 on OS X. It seems like launching
>   Chrome with --enable-ipv6 helps.